# Applying javascript function to multiple div tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html page that as on the index page 16 boxes, Inside on box 3 other boxes are there, I want to interchange the inner boxes periodically:
One box represented as:

```
<div class="box" id="Index_one">
<div class="Divbox" id="Box_three"><img src=''  /><p class="overlap"></p></div>
<div class="Divbox" id="Box_two"><img src=''  /><p class="overlap"> </p></div>
<div class="Divbox" id="Box_one"><img src=''  /><p class="overlap"> </p></div>
</div>
```

As stated before there are 16 of this kind of boxes
I have a javascript function that can adequately switch through if it is called once on one box
Javascript function is:

```
function Animation(Id_value) {
/*Image Changer for Index_two*/
var Id_num = Id_value
var x = 0
var Images = new Array("Box_one", "Box_two", "Box_three");
one = setInterval(function() {
    var Id = "div#" + Id_num + "> div#" + Images[x]
    $(Id).fadeOut(1000);
    x++
    if (x==2){
        clearInterval(one)
        two = setInterval(function() {
            x--
            var Di = "div#" + Id_num + "> div#" + Images[x]
            $(Di).fadeIn(1000);
            if (x==0) {
                clearInterval(two)
                three = setInterval(function() {
                    var Iv = "div#" + Id_num + "> div#" + Images[x]
                    $(Iv).fadeOut(1000);
                    x++
                    if (x==2){
                        clearInterval(three);
                        four = setInterval(function() {
                            x--
                            var Vi = "div#" + Id_num + "> div#" + Images[x]
                            $(Vi).fadeIn(1000);
                            if (x==0) {
                                clearInterval(four)
                                five = setInterval(function() {
                                    var Dv = "div#" + Id_num + "> div#" + Images[x]
                                    $(Dv).fadeOut(1000);
                                    x++
                                    if (x==2) {
                                        clearInterval(five)
                                        six = setInterval(function() {
                                            x--
                                            var Vd = "div#" + Id_num + "> div#" + Images[x]
                                            $(Vd).fadeIn(1000);
                                        }, 1000)
                                    }
                                }, 1000)
                            }
                        }, 1000)
                    }
                }, 1000);
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
}, 1000);
/*End of Image Changer*/
};
```

It does it 3 times, Instead of writing this kind of function custom for all my 16 boxes which i consider redundant, I did this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   Animation("Index_one");
   Animation("Index_two");
   Animation("Index_three");
   Animation("Index_four");
   Animation("Index_five");
   Animation("Index_six");
   Animation("Mid_one");
   Animation("Mid_two");
   Animation("Mid_three");
   Animation("Mid_four");
   Animation("bottom_one");
   Animation("bottom_two");
   Animation("bottom_three");
   Animation("bottom_four");
   Animation("bottom_five");
   Animation("bottom_six");
 }
```

Thinking this should work but did not according to how the function was written, please any help explained properly would be appreciated.

Comment: why do you use setInterval and then clear it every time??? Just use setTimeout...

Comment: @Simon how do you purpose i use setTimeout

Comment: Do you want one at a time `.Divbox` shown in each `.box`?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
// FIRST OPTION
var divlist = ["Index_one","Index_two","Index_three","Index_four","Index_five","Index_six","Mid_one","Mid_two","Mid_three","Mid_four","bottom_one","bottom_two","bottom_three","bottom_four","bottom_five","bottom_six"];
for (div in divlist) {
    Animation(divlist[div]);
}

// SECOND OPTION 
// (having in mind that box class is applied only on targeted divs
$('.box').each(function() {
    Animation(this.id);
});
```

Second option is using jQuery each function. It first finds all of div tags with box class and then iterates over them. During the iteration, each of the found div is called in Animation(this).

Comment: Don't use for-in loops on arrays!

Comment: Thanks .. i understand the first option, would quicly try it out, but i dont understand the second one, please explain it, kinda a noob

Comment: @Lior Would use for(y=0;y<len(divlist);y++) something like that

Comment: It's just an example, I'm quite sure it's not mission critical here.

Comment: @Goran.it what does that 'this' in Animation(this) produce? I need it to produce the Id of that box not class

Comment: this refers to dom node, so if you need the ID in the function then use instead this.id (I've updated the code above to send ID's)

Comment: Mission critical or not, don't answer a question using a technique which is considered error prone and a bad practice, people are learning from this.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/21558566/1233630

Comment: This is a teaching site and so you shouldn't give out bad advice even if it "isn't the point". Also, This is not about optimization, the fact you're saying that means you just don't know the subject enough. Apart from the important issue where for-in iterates over object keys instead of the array indices, It will also not always iterate in the right order which is major if you're dealing with, let say, animations...learn to accept constructive criticism, it's a big part of SO...

Comment: Furthermore,  don't decide for the asker of the question how critical his project or this piece of code is. Also, why is there "obviously no array prototype extension"  you have no idea of other code in the project, or what libraries that might temper with the array or object prototypes he might have included in parts you don't see of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`jQuery.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) to animate elements sequentially.

## HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="fadeAllOut" value="Fade all out!" />
<div class="box" id="Index_one">
    <div class="Divbox" id="Box_three">
        <img src='' />
        <p class="overlap"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="Divbox" id="Box_two">
        <img src='' />
        <p class="overlap"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="Divbox" id="Box_one">
        <img src='' />
        <p class="overlap"></p>
    </div>
    <!-- as many as you need
    <div class="Divbox" id="Box_one">
        <img src='' />
        <p class="overlap"></p>
    </div>
   -->
</div>
```

## JavaScript:

```
$(document).on("click", "#fadeAllOut", function (e) {
    var elems = $(".Divbox");

    //variable for accumulating delay
    var delay = 0;

    //needed duration
    var duration = 500;

    $.each(elems, function (index, element) {
        $(element).delay(delay).fadeOut(duration);
        /*or if you want just hide but not remove elements from layout, use this:        
        .animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, duration);*/

        //accumulate delay
        delay += duration;
    });
});
```

## Here is the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n1k1ch/WKpLK/).

It is just a starting point, trying to understand your requirements

Answer (score 0):

I think, from what it looks like, that the way you called the function (each time with a different id) didn't work because they were starting asynchronously and there for getting entangled in each other's animation.
You can use a recursion and call the next function from within the function itself.
I also replaced your `setInterval` and `clearInterval` calls with `setTimeout`, this make the code a little cleaner and more readable (and even a bit more efficient). 
NOTE: I've replaced also the sixth (the last) call to `setInterval` with `setTimeout` although you don't clear that one (which is a bug, I think).

```
var elements = ["Index_one","Index_two","Index_three","Index_four","Index_five","Index_six","Mid_one","Mid_two","Mid_three","Mid_four","bottom_one","bottom_two","bottom_three","bottom_four","bottom_five","bottom_six"];

function Animation(listIndex, elementList) {
   /*Image Changer for Index_two*/
   var Id_value = elementList[listIndex];
   var Id_num = Id_value
   var x = 0
   var Images = new Array("Box_one", "Box_two", "Box_three");
   one = setTimeout(function() {
       var Id = "div#" + Id_num + "> div#" + Images[x]
       $(Id).fadeOut(1000);
       x++
       if (x==2){
           two = setTimeout(function() {
               x--
               var Di = "div#" + Id_num + "> div#" + Images[x]
               $(Di).fadeIn(1000);
               if (x==0) {
                   three = setTimeout(function() {
                       var Iv = "div#" + Id_num + "> div#" + Images[x]
                       $(Iv).fadeOut(1000);
                       x++
                       if (x==2){
                           four = setTimeout(function() {
                               x--
                               var Vi = "div#" + Id_num + "> div#" + Images[x]
                               $(Vi).fadeIn(1000);
                               if (x==0) {
                                   five = setTimeout(function() {
                                       var Dv = "div#" + Id_num + "> div#" + Images[x]
                                       $(Dv).fadeOut(1000);
                                       x++
                                       if (x==2) {
                                           six = setTimeout(function() {
                                               x--
                                               var Vd = "div#" + Id_num + "> div#" + Images[x] 
                                               $(Vd).fadeIn(1000, function(){
                                                 Animation(++listIndex, elementList); // This will call this function with the next index but only when the fadein animation will finish.
                                               });
                                            }, 1000)
                                       }
                                   }, 1000)
                               }
                           }, 1000)
                       }
                   }, 1000);
               }
           }, 1000);
       }
   }, 1000);
   /*End of Image Changer*/
};

Animation(0, elements) // Call the Animation function with the first element index to start it all off
```

Also, to clean up your code a little, instead of using setInterval (or setTimeout) you can pass the next fadein function as a call back to the jquery fadein method, as the second argument (the complete argument) which will be called when the fadein animation is complete. Like I'v done for the last (six) call to fadein where I call the Animation function with the next element id). You can read about it in jQuery's `fadein` docs:
http://api.jquery.com/fadein/